# Dynamic linking precedence in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, matlab, dyld

I have a software project written in C++ that I'm developing in Xcode 7.1. Part of this program does is output MATLAB *.mat files. MATLAB provides the dylibs to do this: libmat.dylib and libmx.dylib. So I add their path (on a Mac, /Applications/MATLAB_R2015b.app/bin/maci64) to "Linking > Runpath Search Paths" and also to the "Search Paths > Library Search Paths" field.

The problem is, there is another libmat.dylib that lives in /usr/lib. (Funny story, the way I discovered this was by accidentally overwriting the libmat.dylib in /usr/lib, with hilariously disastrous consequences).

Well, I've done this once before but it was a separate build, and I've since completely forgotten: How do I tell the linker that I want the libmat.dylib that lives in the MATLAB directory, and not the one in /usr/lib? In other words, how do I change the order in which these paths are searched? Ordinarily I'd just move the conflicting library or change the name, but doing so will break my OS.